# GitHub Actions: Run cron on three/four branches that change every x months

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a Github Actions Cron, and from my understanding they only run on the `default` branch. However, I need the cron to run on multiple branches (where each branch is a library major version), so I was thinking maybe github actions has a `loop` like feature that I am unaware about, or maybe some setting that I can setup, or even a way to trigger other jobs that reference the branch needed.

The cron runs on a minimum of 3 branches that change everytime we release a new version of the code (every 6 months). We only need the cron to run on the three (or four) most recent versions (branches). Here is the branching structure:

- `beta` - The upcoming release.
- `main` - The current **stable** version of the library.
- `v#.x` - Where the `#` is the library major version before `main` (Examples: `v5.x`, `v6.x`).

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  default:
    steps:
      # The steps to perform on all three/four branches
```